# OpenAM 10.1.0-Xpress Login Error "User has no profile in this organization"

Tags: single-sign-on, openam

I have configured openAM and have following settings.

Go to Access Control
Click on Top Level Realm (root "/")
Click on Authentication Tab
Click on "All Core Settings" button
User Profile Creation is set to "Ignored."

When i logged in with the user, it gives me error 'User has no profile in this organization'. I have check under openAM subjects the user is not shown only first 100 to 150 users are shown, when I search user it show me mine user. After searching the user and login again it does not give any error and login is successfull. Now I restart the OpenAM machine the issue start occuring again. Please help me how to solve this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the 'Ignored' setting has not been applied.

Auth is a 2 step process

1) actually authentication
2) profile search

actually the 2nd step should not be perform when 'Ingored' is configured in core auth.

If this is a multi-instance setup check that configuration data store is replicated correctly and that config changes do propagate to OpenAM.

Enabling 'message' level debugging in looking in the debug logs will help you to solve this.

Comment: I have enabled the Circle of trust and I have my service provider application, now I logged in using my test application the web page opens and after entering credential my SAML response has missing the attribute AND i CANNOT LOGGED IN.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to be more specific.

Which product is used as IdP?
Which product is used as SP?

Where do you get 'User has no profile in this organization error ... IdP or SP?

If on IdP and IdP is OpenAM then it's related to plain OpenAM auth as I explained.